429 To many requests using YTDL
I was using my app to stream some youtube songs, until i went to play another one and was wondering why it didnt play. Looked at my console to see 429 to many requests, I know this is the server basically saying back off you have made to many requests in our allotted timeframe. But i have been blocked for 3 days.
any idea on how long its gona last? as i had exponential backoff but it seems like 10 songs in 4 hours to much and I'm mega confused as I've been doing this for the last 12 months with no issues.
any answer would be gratefully appreciated.
Not to get 429 after playing 10 songs in 4 hours. I thought I hit my quota but I only used 1000 / 10000 units so now im mega confused. And it doesnt refresh it looks like an IP block

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
